# Restringing guitar – is it safe to remove all strings at once?

Tags: electric-guitar, strings, maintenance

Considering the present truss rod adjustment is good (Vintage Gibson SG with very old strings), is it generally acceptable to remove all the strings before restringing? It's just so much easier to recondition the fret board this way. I'm planning to restring with medium gauge cobalt.